# Drupal 7.x: how to create a new node with PHP input format?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I want execute custom PHP script that will delete all nodes of a particular type (Feed items).
How to create a new node with PHP input format, so I can paste code into the node body? Please specify detailed steps.

```
$node_type = 'Feed items';

  //fetch the nodes we want to delete
  $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type='%s'",$node_type);
  while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)){
    node_delete($row->nid);
    $deleted_count+=1;
  }
  //simple debug message so we can see what had been deleted.
  drupal_set_message("$deleted_count nodes have been deleted");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Do you simply want to execute that PHP code, once? Or whenever a node of a certain type is created?

If you just want to execute the PHP code once, you can install the devel module (http://drupal.org/project/devel) and paste your code in `<your_site_url>/devel/php`

--EDIT

Another option would be to create a php page that bootstraps Drupal and runs your code:
http://www.avenuewebmedia.com/drupalbootstrap-connect-drupal-external-php-script

Comment: I just want to execute the PHP code once, this is a one time thing. But I would prefer not to install additional module just for this task, I want simplest way.

Comment: Added another solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed myself how to do this: I had to enable the "PHP filter" module first (in Drupal core, disabled by default). In admin > Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats > Add text format, in "Enabled filters" mark "PHP evaluator", in Roles select 'admin', save configuration.
Then I created a new node (article), set the input format to PHP, pasted the code into the node body, added a title and clicked submit. Code has been executed. Sure, we need to delete the node when done.